# module "QtQuick" plugin "qtquick2plugin" not found in static linked application

Tags: static, qml, qt-quick

I builded static version of the Qt libraries and compile the test application based on QtQuick2ApplicationViewer. When starting it produces an error:

```
file:///F:/qt_projects/untitled9-build-5_0_0_static-__________________________/qml/untitled9/main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" plugin "qtquick2plugin" not found 
     import QtQuick 2.0 
     ^ 
Remove me: fixing toplevel window flags
Unable to find a renderable master window QtQuick2ApplicationViewer(0x28fe38) when trying to render QtQuick2ApplicationViewer(0x28fe38)  ( QRect(8,30 116x0) ).
```

how i can add plugin "qtquick2plugin" to my aplication?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. I've sent bugreport to Qt-community:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28357

This link contains description and my solution of your problem. Unfortunately it doesn't help me, but really may help in your case or just clear the situation.

Comment: I have same problem and i test suggested solution. Not works!

Answer (score 1):

Qt warns about this on configuring a static build (*or at least it does so in recent versions*):

> Note: Using static linking will disable the use of dynamically
> loaded plugins. Make sure to import all needed static plugins,
> or compile needed modules into the library.

And `qtquick2plugin` is one of those, apparently. Here's also [some documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins) on the matter.

For CMake, starting with Qt 5.14, there is [qt5_import_qml_plugins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cmake-qt5-import-qml-plugins.html) function (*and hopefully `qt6_import_qml_plugins` in Qt 6 too*):

```
get_target_property(QT_TARGET_TYPE Qt5::Core TYPE)
if(${QT_TARGET_TYPE} STREQUAL "STATIC_LIBRARY")
    find_package(Qt5QmlImportScanner REQUIRED)
    qt5_import_qml_plugins(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
endif()
```

For Qt versions older than 5.14 one can use [this external module](https://github.com/OlivierLDff/QtStaticCMake).

Comment: Works for Qt6 with the obvious changes: `Qt6QmlImportScanner`, `qt6_import_qml_plugins`... thanks!

Comment: @cbuchart i dont understand what you did, I'm getting this same problem, i created a **new** question could you take a look at it on my profile, please?